# Stochastic processes-Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-processes

I hope someone can help me with the following exercise...
Show that $ \int_0^t s \, dB_s =tB_t-\int_0^t B_s \, ds $, for each $t>0$, where $B$ is a Brownian motion.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: This is direct from Itô's formula applied to $X_t=tB_t$.

Comment: Since you now accepted a remarkably succinct answer, I hope you checked for yourself that Itô's formula did not introduce supplementary terms in the differentials involved. To wit, let me remind you that the "integration by parts" formula $X_sdB_s=d(X_sB_s)-B_sdX_s$ is not true for every process $(X_s)$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to start with integration by parts:

$sdB_s=d(sB_s)-B_sds$

Comment: No prob.  Glad to be of help.